# Swift, custom UITableViewCell with UIImageView. Need to resize cell to image height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uikit

I'am trying to make app, that will show images in table view.
I have custom cell with image view. It only must download image data from url:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tweetImage: UIImageView!
var imageData : MediaItem? { didSet { updateUI() }}

func updateUI(){
    tweetImage.image = nil
    if let url = imageData?.url {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            tweetImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the cell height was changed after the download. It must be equal to the height of the image. I set auto dimension in viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

I set "aspect fit" to image, I get strange results. The image extends beyond the boundaries of the cell. Maybe i need to set some constraints... I don't know.

Results:

[image: result of it]

But i need this:

[image: nice result]

Comment: Try to call `reloadData()` on `viewWillAppear()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to load images async:

After you load and set new `UIImage`, you can reload specific cell via `UITableView` function:

`- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

In your UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "imageDidLoadNotification:", name:"CellDidLoadImageDidLoadNotification", object: nil)
}

func imageDidLoadNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if  let cell = notification.object as? UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    }
}
```

In your UITableViewCell

```
func updateUI(){
    tweetImage.image = nil
    if let url = imageData?.url {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            tweetImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("CellDidLoadImageDidLoadNotification", object: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If is it the last cell, it taking a infinite looping of reloading that cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dinamic table with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, then you need to set your constraint properly ([image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6v2vrosb3w91iaj/K%C3%A9perny%C5%91fot%C3%B3%202015-08-04%20-%2011.49.25.png?dl=0)). (for correct width and height, I suggest you to use aspect ratio)

With static table view, you should implement `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`, and count the cell size manually.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you need to set constraints for your image in the cell

[image: screenshot]

Maybe this screenshot will help you