# Resize table cell after image downloaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library to download image and load into image view inside a table cell.

I want to resize the table cell after the image is downloaded. Please advice. Many thanks.

Cell is not resize correctly after image set into image view
[image]

Cell resize correctly after dequeue and load again

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(GagListTableViewCell.cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GagListTableViewCell
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    let gagDataCommand = gagDataSource[indexPath.row]

    if let caption = gagDataCommand.caption {
        cell.captionLabel.text = caption
    }

    if let imageUrlStr = gagDataCommand.images?.normal {
        if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageUrlStr) {                
            cell.gagImage.sd_setImageWithURL(imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: AppConstants.imagePlaceHolderName), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                 //guess I need to redraw the layout here
            })
        } else {
            //fail to get image url, set placeholder image to the cell instead
            cell.gagImage.image = UIImage(named: AppConstants.imagePlaceHolderName)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you use auto layout?

Comment: Can you try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on `tablecell` after setting the downloaded image

Comment: Go through following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805341/swift-custom-uitableviewcell-with-uiimageview-need-to-resize-cell-to-image-hei

Comment: Yes I am using auto layout. I tried layoutIfNeeded but cannot fix the problem.

Comment: Is problem solved? if yes then please provide a solution because i am also facing same issue and didn't get any proper solution.

Comment: @RakeshPatel do you have the image size return by the back-end service? If yes then you can use it to calculate the frame of UIImageView to prevent this problem.

Comment: No. No any size information return by back-end service. Is there any other option?

Comment: @RakeshPatel In that case, after you downloaded the image. You can use the image size to do the cell calculation and stored in the cache (a dictionary to cache the cell height). And reload the row / reload the whole table.

So the table view can use the cached height to resize your cell properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use automatic dimension for tableview cell.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Yes I have set rowHeight as UITableViewAutomaticDimension. It doesn't work for the case when placeholder image is set and image is required to download

Comment: you are downloading image separately??

Comment: Can you change the image view to aspect fill.

Comment: I have to use scale to Scale to Fill in my case. And I have attached my source code. Thanks for the help.